# How can i get feedbacks for Google Maps objects (cafes, restaurants)?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

How can i get feedbacks for Google Maps objects (cafes, restaurants)?
Is any public API (SDK) available?

Comment: What do you mean by 'feedbacks'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/)

Sounds like you are looking for "reviews", which are available in the [place details response](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i was looking for! Is there any Java SDK available (found Javascript only)?